# Python: Add position number to string element in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list and would like to add an addition to the first list with the position number:

```
names = ["one", "two"]
names_numbers = [x + '\n(%s)' for x in names]
```

So that I get:

```
desired output = ['one\n(0)', 'two\n(1)']
```

However, I am struggling with the middle step. I found a way for one element in a string, but not for every element in a list, being flexible in the length of the list. 
I also don't want a tuple, but the number inside the string!

Comment: Should this be `['zero\n(0)', 'one\n(1)']`, indexing from 1 would be harder.

Comment: That would also work

Comment: To answer your specific question, this would work `names_numbers=['{}\n({})'.format(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(names)]`